# Perform feature selection in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I am working on a Python project involving regression to predict some values.
The input is a data set consisting of **70 features** which are a mix of **categorical** and **ordinal** variables. The dependent variable is **continuous**.

The input would be data and **the number of significant variables**.

i had some questions which are mentioned below.

1] Is there a way to perform feature selection using forward selection technique in **Tensorflow**?

2] are there **alternatives** to feature selection ?

Comment: I am not an expert in NN but isn't the ability of NN to automatically perform feature selection one of it`s benefits ? You do not have to I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problem

I have N number of features (N = 70 for example) and I want to select the K top features.  (1) How could I do this in TensorFlow and (2) what alternatives are there to feature selection.

## Discussion

I will show one way to limit the number of N features to at most K using a variant of L1 loss.  As for alternatives to feature selection there are many depending on what you want to achieve.  If you can go outside of TensorFlow then you could use Decision Trees or a Random Forest and simply constrain the number of leaves to use at most K features.  If you must use TensorFlow and you want an alternative to top K features that regularizes your weights you could use random dropout or L2 loss.  Again, it really depends on what you want to achieve when looking for an alternative to top K features.

## Solution to Top K of N features.

Supposed our TensorFlow graph is defined as follows

```
import tensorflow as tf

size = 4

x_in = tf.placeholder( shape=[None,size] , dtype=tf.float32 )
y_in = tf.placeholder( shape=[None] , dtype=tf.float32 )
l1_weight = tf.placeholder( shape=[] , dtype=tf.float32 )

m = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( shape=[size,1] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 ) , dtype=tf.float32 )
m = tf.nn.relu(m)
b = tf.Variable([-10], dtype=tf.float32 )

predict = tf.squeeze( tf.nn.xw_plus_b(x_in,m,b) )

l1_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(m))
loss = tf.reduce_mean( tf.square( y_in - predict ) ) + l1_loss * l1_weight

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

m_all_0 = tf.zeros( [size,1] , dtype=tf.float32 )
zerod_feature_count = tf.reduce_sum( tf.cast( tf.equal( m , m_all_0 ) , dtype=tf.float32 ) )
k = size - zerod_feature_count
```

Let's define some data and use this

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,0],[4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,0],[4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,0],[4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,0],[5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,0],[5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,0],[4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,0],[5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,0],[4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,0],[4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,0],[5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,0],[4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,0],[4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,0],[4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,0],[5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,0],[5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,0],[5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4,0],[5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,0],[5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,0],[5.1,3.8,1.5,0.3,0],[5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,0],[5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,0],[4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,0],[5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,0],[4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,0],[5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,0],[5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,0],[5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,0],[5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,0],[4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2,0],[4.8,3.1,1.6,0.2,0],[5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4,0],[5.2,4.1,1.5,0.1,0],[5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2,0],[4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,0],[5.0,3.2,1.2,0.2,0],[5.5,3.5,1.3,0.2,0],[4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,0],[4.4,3.0,1.3,0.2,0],[5.1,3.4,1.5,0.2,0],[5.0,3.5,1.3,0.3,0],[4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3,0],[4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2,0],[5.0,3.5,1.6,0.6,0],[5.1,3.8,1.9,0.4,0],[4.8,3.0,1.4,0.3,0],[5.1,3.8,1.6,0.2,0],[4.6,3.2,1.4,0.2,0],[5.3,3.7,1.5,0.2,0],[5.0,3.3,1.4,0.2,0],[7.0,3.2,4.7,1.4,1],[6.4,3.2,4.5,1.5,1],[6.9,3.1,4.9,1.5,1],[5.5,2.3,4.0,1.3,1],[6.5,2.8,4.6,1.5,1],[5.7,2.8,4.5,1.3,1],[6.3,3.3,4.7,1.6,1],[4.9,2.4,3.3,1.0,1],[6.6,2.9,4.6,1.3,1],[5.2,2.7,3.9,1.4,1],[5.0,2.0,3.5,1.0,1],[5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,1],[6.0,2.2,4.0,1.0,1],[6.1,2.9,4.7,1.4,1],[5.6,2.9,3.6,1.3,1],[6.7,3.1,4.4,1.4,1],[5.6,3.0,4.5,1.5,1],[5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0,1],[6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5,1],[5.6,2.5,3.9,1.1,1],[5.9,3.2,4.8,1.8,1],[6.1,2.8,4.0,1.3,1],[6.3,2.5,4.9,1.5,1],[6.1,2.8,4.7,1.2,1],[6.4,2.9,4.3,1.3,1],[6.6,3.0,4.4,1.4,1],[6.8,2.8,4.8,1.4,1],[6.7,3.0,5.0,1.7,1],[6.0,2.9,4.5,1.5,1],[5.7,2.6,3.5,1.0,1],[5.5,2.4,3.8,1.1,1],[5.5,2.4,3.7,1.0,1],[5.8,2.7,3.9,1.2,1],[6.0,2.7,5.1,1.6,1],[5.4,3.0,4.5,1.5,1],[6.0,3.4,4.5,1.6,1],[6.7,3.1,4.7,1.5,1],[6.3,2.3,4.4,1.3,1],[5.6,3.0,4.1,1.3,1],[5.5,2.5,4.0,1.3,1],[5.5,2.6,4.4,1.2,1],[6.1,3.0,4.6,1.4,1],[5.8,2.6,4.0,1.2,1],[5.0,2.3,3.3,1.0,1],[5.6,2.7,4.2,1.3,1],[5.7,3.0,4.2,1.2,1],[5.7,2.9,4.2,1.3,1],[6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,1],[5.1,2.5,3.0,1.1,1],[5.7,2.8,4.1,1.3,1]])

x = data[:,0:4]
y = data[:,-1]

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Let's define a reusable trial function that can test different weights of l1_loss

```
def trial(weight=1):
    print "initial m,loss",sess.run([m,loss],feed_dict={x_in:x, y_in:y, l1_weight:0})
    for _ in range(10000):
        sess.run(train,feed_dict={x_in:x, y_in:y, l1_weight:0})
    print "after training m,loss",sess.run([m,loss],feed_dict={x_in:x, y_in:y, l1_weight:0})
    for _ in range(10000):
        sess.run(train,feed_dict={x_in:x, y_in:y, l1_weight:weight})
        if sess.run(k) <= 3 :
            break
    print "after l1 loss m",sess.run([m,loss],feed_dict={x_in:x, y_in:y, l1_weight:weight})
```

Then we'll try it out

```
print "The number of non-zero parameters is",sess.run(k)
print "Doing a training session"
trial()
print "The number of non-zero parameters is",sess.run(k)
```

And the results look good

```
The number of non-zero parameters is 4.0
Doing a training session
initial m,loss [array([[0.75030506],
       [0.4959089 ],
       [0.646675  ],
       [0.44027993]], dtype=float32), 8.228347]
after training m,loss [array([[1.1898338 ],
       [1.0033115 ],
       [0.15164669],
       [0.16414128]], dtype=float32), 0.68957466]
after l1 loss m [array([[1.250356  ],
       [0.92532456],
       [0.10235767],
       [0.        ]], dtype=float32), 2.9621665]
The number of non-zero parameters is 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Panchishin for the help.

Was trying out the code and ran into an error mentioned below.

zerod_feature_count = tf.gather_sum( tf.equal( m , m_all_0 ) ) creates 
**AttributeError:** module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gather_sum'

any possible fixes ?

Comment: Sorry @fdgodabhi , I usually test my code before posting to SO but I rushed this time.   I fixed the first code block and I'm reviewing the rest.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I updated the code and showed some output.  After completing this exercise I'd say that using L1 to enforce this isn't a computationally efficient method.  It was pretty kludgy.  As per the discussion, using something other than tensorflow would work better if all you are looking for is the top K of a linear correlation.